# Vue js as a widget on another site

Tags: web, web-applications, vue.js

I was wondering if it was possible to build a vuejs component that could be embedded into another site. The thing is the component would show up several times on the website so I wouldn't have access to a root element. I know a way to do this in react but I'd rather do it in Vue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

I created this project a long time ago https://github.com/lmarqs/odw-form. The objective was to create embeddable components to be  into other sites.

It was created using vue-cli but I had to adapt it.

Basically, I created a new entry file to the webpack ([main.prod.js](https://github.com/lmarqs/odw-form/blob/master/src/main.prod.js)). This entry installs the components on Vue. So in the html is is possible to create somenthing like this:

```
<div id="app-1">
  <my-component1></my-component1>
  <my-component2></my-component2>
</div>
<div id="app-2">
  <my-component1></my-component1>
  <my-component2></my-component2>
</div>
<script>
  var app1 = new Vue({
    el: "app-1"
  });

  var app2 = new Vue({
    el: "app-2"
  });
</script>
```

After creating the new entry I setted the entry on [webpack.base.conf.js](https://github.com/lmarqs/odw-form/blob/master/build/webpack.base.conf.js#L14)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: isProduction ? ["./src/main.prod.js"] : ["./src/main.js"]
  }
}
```

Then, running the `npm run build` command the embeddable css and js files are created into `/dist`folder.

Comment: What if I wanted to have multiple instances where each 


    `<div id="app" query="foo">
    <my-component></mycomponent>
    </div>
    <div id="app" query="bar">
    <my-component></mycomponent>
    </div>`

Comment: I you could `var app1 = new Vue({ el: "app1" });`, `var app2 = new Vue({ el: "app2" });` and you would have diferent instances of the same component.

Comment: Would having those multiple instances affect performance in anyway?

Comment: I have never any performance issues. Running `npm run build` the templates are transpiled to render functions (same concept used on react). Those render functions are really light.

Answer (score 1):

I know,i am not answering your question as you want (using vue component in another site).

> It would be perfect if you create a component and use it in frameworks like Angular,React,Vue etc.You can do it with [Stencil.js](https://stenciljs.com)

[By clicking here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqMYaT1GlWY&list=PL55RiY5tL51pIQNcOLDjnaQJYuj_GjVSz) you see an awesome tutorial about it.

Comment: That looks awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Yes i know,i updated my answer so you can see a great tutorial made by academind.

Answer (score 0):

You can put more than one root elements in one site. Every component needs to be rendered under a root. Furthermore you always have access to the root via the `$root` property. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking towards [vue-custom-element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-custom-element)

Answer (score 0):

As I found this question years later on google, I would like to propose another alternative for others ending up on this post like me. Namely, web components.

**Vue Docs:**
https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue

It will export a single vue-component so it can be reused on any other website by importing a script and using your custom tag `<my-component>`.