# How do I package a Vue CLI 3 app as a configurable widget?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cdn, vue-cli-3

I have made a Vue app with Vue CLI 3, which I would like to distribute as a widget, via a CDN.

The way I see apps like Hotjar doing this is through a snippet which refers to a script on a CDN, with a variable ('user_key' or something like that,) and the variable is passed into the script.

How could I do something similar?

I noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181064/3019008) and think it's a starting point, but it doesn't really address the above question.

Comment: Have a [thorough read through of this documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html)

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't really tell me anything about how to have my script expose a top-level variable and pass it down.

Comment: Vue uses the idea of a `plugin`, so you would do something like `Vue.use(MyWidget, { option: val })`. perhaps you need both of these.